# Regular Expression Matching -Java

Tags: java, regex

I am taking input from a file in following format:

```
(int1,int2) (int3,int4)
```

Now I want to read int1, int2, int3 and int4 in my Java code.
How can I do it with regular expression matching in java. Thankx.

Comment: what have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Will the values you wanna get always be prefixed by `int`? For example, `int42`, `int256`, etc.?

Comment: no these are int, like: (2,3) (4,5)

Comment: @sp00m I think `int1` are only place holders, so an example would be `(1,24) (324,42)`...

Comment: I tried to learn and did this but it doesn't removes comma, How do I remove that:`String s = "(3,4)";
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\(\\)]*)\\)");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

  while(m.find())
  {
   System.out.println(m.group( 1 ));
  }`

Comment: @Harsh please put your tries in the question and not in the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String[] ints = "(2,3) (4,5)".split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ints));
// prints [, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

To avoid empty values:

```
String[] ints = "(2,3) (4,5)".replaceAll("^\\D*(.*)\\D*$", "$1").split("\\D+");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ints));
// prints [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I like that solution... Its cleaner regex, although it isn't so demanding on the format

Comment: It gets even simpler if you exchange `[^\\d]+` for the equivalent `\\D+`

Answer (score 4):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)\\s+\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
String input = "(123,456) (789,012)";

Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

if (m.matches()) {
  int a = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 10);
  int b = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2), 10);
  int c = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3), 10);
  int d = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4), 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
String str = "(1,2) (3,4)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\) \\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)").matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1)); // number 1
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on your own method, you can use a much simpler regex:

```
String s = "(1,2) (3,4)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
String[] values = s.substring(1).split("\\D+");
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)\\s*\\((\\d*),(\\d*)\\)"`