# Using delimiters in Scanner

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, delimiter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression Matching -Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424229/regular-expression-matching-java)

I'm using a FileInputStream in the Scanner.
I have to extract input of this form:
(int,int) (int,int)
I need to store those 4 numbers in an array.
I've tried using delimiters to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working!
in is the Scanner object.

```
in.useDelimiter("( * | * , * | * ) *");
int[] x = new int[4]; 
int k = 0;
while (in.hasNext() && k<4) 
{   
if(in.hasNextInt())
{
    x[k] = in.nextInt();
    k++;
}
else if(in.next("nil").equalsIgnoreCase("nil"))
{
    x[k] = 0;
    k++;
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Edit1: I also have to ensure that the input is IN this format.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424229/regular-expression-matching-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
String x = "(10,56)(2,8)(100,5)";

String arr[] = x.replaceAll("[(|)]","").split(",");
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    } // give u perfect result

 or

String arr[]=x.split("[(d,d)]");
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    } // result with some whitespce
```